# How do I use the prototyping area on a SparkFun MicroSD Card shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, sd-card

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I'm using this popular shield: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12761

There is a breadboard area in the middle of the shield. But what confuses me is the lack of lines (order). On normal breadboards you can tell which row would be at the same voltage. If I wanted to put something on this prototyping area, how would I connect it? For example an LED, which would have a resistor attached to the positive side going to 5V and the negative side going to ground?

Comment: By soldering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of board, "pad per hole", has no pre-made interconnects. If you use thin enough wire sometimes you can push two pieces of wire into the same hole before you solder, say a resistor lead and another wire to connect to the next component. You can also solder an interconnect wire to the protruding leg of a DIP chip. You can make a buss for ground or 5v by assigning a whole row for that purpose, on the top side wire everything that needs to connect to that buss, and on the bottom side solder a straight piece of bare wire to all those wire ends in that row.